# Formula for the 3 hands to coincide in a clock, no matter wether the clock is a conventional one or not

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find out a formula for the clock's hands to coincide no matter it's a conventional one or not. Here is the progress i made, but I'm stuck. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZO4Q.jpg)

Comment: i want to make t as the subject

Comment: Hey welcome to MathSE! Avoid using images to describe your question. Use MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What do you mean when you say I am trying to find out a formula for the clock's hands to coincide ? Does it mean number of times they coincide in a day ?

Comment: how many times they coincide in a day@SagarM

Answer (score 0):

In the time the seconds hand made a full rotation, the minute hand made $\frac{1}{60}$ of a full rotation and the hour hand made $\frac{1}{720}$ (so $\frac{1}{12}$ of the progress of the minute hand) of a full rotation. So if the seconds hand made t rotations, the minute hand made $\frac{t}{60}$ rotations and the hours hand made $\frac{t}{720}$ rotations in that same time.

The first time (after midnight) the hour and minute hand meet occurs when the minute hand made a full rotation and catches up to the hour hand, at which point the amount the minute hand rotated is exactly one full rotation more than the rotation the hour hand made, so $t = \frac{t}{12} + 1$. Solving this equation gives you $t = \frac{12}{11}$, so 1 hour, 5 minutes and about 27 seconds after midnight. Every $\frac{12}{11}$ hours the hour and minute hand meet, that's 22 times per day - but you can check that the only point where the seconds hand is also in the same place is at 12am and 12pm.

Since you tried it using trigonometric functions, here's an alternative way:

Let's suppose the seconds hand moves $\alpha$ degrees. In the amount of time that the seconds hade rotated $\alpha$ degrees, the minute hand rotates $\frac{\alpha}{60}$ of the whole clock, while the hours hand rotates $\frac{\alpha}{720}$ of the whole clock.

We want to know $\alpha$ for which all three hands are in the same place, meaning

$\cos(\alpha) = \cos(\frac{\alpha}{60}) = \cos(\frac{\alpha}{720})$ and

$\sin(\alpha) = \sin(\frac{\alpha}{60}) = \sin(\frac{\alpha}{720})$

This is the case if $\alpha = 1440\pi \cdot n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, or in other words every 259,200°

Since the seconds hand makes $60\cdot 24=1,440$ full rotations over the whole day, we search for $n\geq 0$ for which $\alpha = 259,200° \cdot n$ is less than $1440\cdot 360°=518,400°$. This is the case only for $n \in \{0,1\}$. So there's 2 times when all hands are in the same place:

After the seconds hand turned $\alpha = 259,200 \cdot 0 = 0$ degrees, so at midnight.

After the seconds hand turned $\alpha = 259,200 \cdot 1 = 259,200$ degrees, that is after 720 full rotations or 12 hours, so at noon.

Comment: wt abt an unconventional clock? R there a general formula for the 3 hands to coincide?

Comment: Can you clarify for me what you mean by "unconventional clock"?

Comment: like a clock that the second-hand takes 20s to go one full circle instead of 60s

Comment: so r there a general formula that no matters how the clocks is, we can always find out when will it coincide

Comment: So you mean if the hands of the clock went (in your example) three times as fast? Then of course there's three times as many instances per day where all three hands coincide than with a conventional clock. In general, if your unconventional clock goes x times as fast as a conventional clock, then we are looking for all natural numbers n such that $259,200° \cdot n < 518,400°\cdot x \Rightarrow n < 2x$. So there are $\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ instances per day where they all overlap.